# recyclerview not displaying sqlite product data in fragment using kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

i am new in android development. i am facing problem in viewing products. with the same code i am getting the customer information.

The problem is that its not showing anything... the fragment is blank when i open it although the data is present... Any idea why its now showing any data? Im not getting any error just that the data isnt showing

Code

```
public class UsageSettings2 extends Fragment {
MainData mDatabaseHelper;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
UserDataHelper mHelper;
private List<UsageHelper> usage = new ArrayList<>();
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private UsageAdapter mAdapter;
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_usage2, container, false);

    final MainData myDBHlpr = new MainData(getActivity());
    db = myDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usagelist);
        //Add the data first
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        //and then create a object and pass the lis
        mAdapter = new UsageAdapter(usage);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Cursor csr = myDBHlpr.getAllQuestions2(getActivity());
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {

        String name = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("Name"));
        int sent = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex("MessagesSent"));
        int recieved = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex("MessagesRecieved"));
        int total = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex("Messages"));
        String time = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("TimeSpent"));

        new UsageHelper(name,sent,recieved,total,time);


        int profile_counts = myDBHlpr.getProfilesCount2();
        Log.d("FFF", String.valueOf(profile_counts));


    }



        return rootView;
    }
}
Adapter

public class UsageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsageAdapter.UsageViewHolder>{

private List<UsageHelper> mUsageHelper;

public UsageAdapter(List<UsageHelper> UsageAdapter) {
    this.mUsageHelper = UsageAdapter;
}

public class UsageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView mName;
    public TextView mSent;
    public TextView mRecieved;
    public TextView mTotal;
    public TextView mTime;

    public UsageViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        mSent = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sent);
        mRecieved = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.recieved);
        mTotal = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.total);
        mTime = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.time);
    }
}
```

this the code for the product
Code for productrecyclerview

```
package com.abc.test1.Adapters

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import com.abc.test1.Addproduct
import com.abc.test1.R
import com.abc.test1.Models.Product
import java.util.ArrayList

class ProductRecyclerAdapter(productsList: List<Product>, internal var context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductRecyclerAdapter.TaskViewHolder>() {

    private var productsList: List<Product> = ArrayList()
    init {
        this.productsList = productsList
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TaskViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_products, parent, false)
        return TaskViewHolder(view)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TaskViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val products = productsList[position]
        holder.pname.text = products.pname
        holder.pprice.text = products.pprice
        holder.ppc.text = products.ppc
        holder.list_products.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.context, R.color.colorSuccess)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val i = Intent(context, Addproduct::class.java)
            i.putExtra("Mode" , "E")
            i.putExtra("Id", products.id)
            i.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            context.startActivity(i)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return productsList.size
    }

    inner class TaskViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var pname: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.pName) as TextView
        var pprice: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.pPrice) as TextView
        var ppc: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.pPc) as TextView
        var list_products: LinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.list_Products) as LinearLayout
    }

}
```

code for dbhelper

```
package com.abc.test1.DBHandler

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import android.util.Log
import com.abc.test1.Models.Client
import com.abc.test1.Models.Product
import java.util.*

class DatabaseHandler(context: Context?) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DatabaseHandler.DB_NAME, null, DatabaseHandler.DB_VERSION) {

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        val CREATE_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME1 ($CID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $CNAME TEXT,$CADDRESS TEXT,$SALESMAN TEXT);"
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE1)
        val CREATE_TABLE2 = "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME2 ($PID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $PNAME TEXT,$PPRICE INT,$PPC TEXT);"
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE2)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        val DROP_TABLE1 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_NAME1"
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE1)
        val DROP_TABLE2 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_NAME2"
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE2)
        onCreate(db)
    }

    fun addClient(client: Client): Boolean {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(CNAME, client.cname)
        values.put(CADDRESS, client.caddress)
        values.put(SALESMAN, client.saleman)
        val _success = db.insert(TABLE_NAME1, null, values)
        db.close()
        Log.v("InsertedId", "$_success")
        return (Integer.parseInt("$_success") != -1)
    }

    fun getClient(_id: Int): Client {
        val clients = Client()
        val db = writableDatabase
        val selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM $TABLE_NAME1 WHERE $CID = $_id"
        val cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)

        cursor?.moveToFirst()
        clients.id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CID)))
        clients.cname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CNAME))
        clients.caddress = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CADDRESS))
        clients.saleman = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SALESMAN))
        cursor.close()
        return clients
    }

    fun client(): List<Client> {
        val clientList = ArrayList<Client>()
        val db = writableDatabase
        val selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM $TABLE_NAME1"
        val cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    val clients = Client()
                    clients.id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CID)))
                    clients.cname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CNAME))
                    clients.caddress = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CADDRESS))
                    clients.saleman = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SALESMAN))
                    clientList.add(clients)
                } while (cursor.moveToNext())
            }
        }
        cursor.close()
        return clientList
    }

    fun updateClient(clients: Client): Boolean {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(CNAME, clients.cname)
        values.put(CADDRESS, clients.caddress)
        values.put(SALESMAN, clients.saleman)
        val _success = db.update(TABLE_NAME1, values, "$CID=?", arrayOf(clients.id.toString())).toLong()
        db.close()
        return Integer.parseInt("$_success") != -1
    }

    fun deleteClient(_id: Int): Boolean {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val _success = db.delete(TABLE_NAME1, "$CID=?", arrayOf(_id.toString())).toLong()
        db.close()
        return Integer.parseInt("$_success") != -1
    }

    fun deleteAllClient(): Boolean {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val _success = db.delete(TABLE_NAME1, null, null).toLong()
        db.close()
        return Integer.parseInt("$_success") != -1
    }
    fun addProduct(product: Product): Boolean {
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(PNAME, product.pname)
        values.put(PPRICE, product.pprice)
        values.put(PPC, product.ppc)
        val _success = this.writableDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME2, null, values)
        Log.v("InsertedId", "$_success")
        return (Integer.parseInt("$_success") != -1)
    }

    fun getProduct(_id: Int): Product {
        val products = Product()
        val db = writableDatabase
        val selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM $TABLE_NAME2 WHERE $PID = $_id"
        val cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)

        cursor?.moveToFirst()
        products.id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PID)))
        products.pname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PNAME))
        products.pprice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PPRICE))
        products.ppc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PPC))
        cursor.close()
        return products
    }

    fun product(): List<Product> {
        val productList = ArrayList<Product>()
        val db = writableDatabase
        val selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM $TABLE_NAME2"
        val cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    val products = Product()
                    products.id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PID)))
                    products.pname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PNAME))
                    products.pprice = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PPRICE))
                    products.ppc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PPC))
                    productList.add(products)
                } while (cursor.moveToNext())
            }
        }
        cursor.close()
        return productList
    }

    fun updateProduct(products: Product): Boolean {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(PNAME, products.pname)
        values.put(PNAME, products.pprice)
        values.put(PNAME, products.ppc)
        val _success = db.update(TABLE_NAME2, values, "$PID=?", arrayOf(products.id.toString())).toLong()
        db.close()
        return Integer.parseInt("$_success") != -1
    }

    fun deleteProduct(_id: Int): Boolean {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val _success = db.delete(TABLE_NAME2, "$PID=?", arrayOf(_id.toString())).toLong()
        db.close()
        return Integer.parseInt("$_success") != -1
    }

    fun deleteAllProducts(): Boolean {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val _success = db.delete(TABLE_NAME2, null, null).toLong()
        db.close()
        return Integer.parseInt("$_success") != -1
    }
    companion object {
        private val DB_VERSION = 1
        private val DB_NAME = "Invoicedb"
        private val TABLE_NAME1 = "Clients"
        private val CID = "Id"
        private val CNAME = "CName"
        private val CADDRESS = "CAddress"
        private val SALESMAN = "Salesman"
        private val TABLE_NAME2 = "Products"
        private val PID = "Id"
        private val PNAME = "PName"
        private val PPRICE = "PPrice"
        private val PPC = "Ppc"
    }
}
```

For adding product am using a new Activity
Addproduct

```
package com.abc.test1

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
import android.view.View
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog
import android.view.MenuItem
import com.abc.test1.Models.Product
import com.abc.test1.DBHandler.DatabaseHandler
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_addproduct.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.list_products.*

class Addproduct : AppCompatActivity() {
    var dbHandler: DatabaseHandler? = null
    var isEditMode = false
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addproduct)
        initDB()
        initOperations()
    }
    private fun initDB() {
        dbHandler = DatabaseHandler(this)
        btn_delete_product.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        if (intent != null && intent.getStringExtra("Mode") == "E") {
            isEditMode = true
            val products: Product = dbHandler!!.getProduct(intent.getIntExtra("Id",0))
            product_name.setText(products.pname)
            product_price.setText(products.pprice)
            ppc.setText(products.ppc)
            btn_delete_product.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    private fun initOperations() {
        if (!isEditMode)
            else
            btn_save_product.text = "UPDATE"
        btn_save_product.setOnClickListener {
            var success: Boolean
            if (!isEditMode) {
                val products: Product = Product()
                products.pname = product_name.text.toString()
                products.pprice = pPrice.text.toString()
                products.ppc = ppc.text.toString()
                success = dbHandler?.addProduct(products) as Boolean
            } else {
                val products: Product = Product()
                btn_save_product.text = getString(R.string.update)
                products.id = intent.getIntExtra("Id", 0)
                products.pname = product_name.text.toString()
                products.pprice = pPrice.text.toString()
                products.ppc = ppc.text.toString()
                success = dbHandler?.updateProduct(products) as Boolean
            }

            if (success)
                finish()
        }

        btn_delete_product.setOnClickListener {
            val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Info").setMessage("Click 'YES' Delete the Task.")
                .setPositiveButton("YES") { dialog, _ ->
                    val success = dbHandler?.deleteProduct(intent.getIntExtra("Id", 0)) as Boolean
                    if (success)
                        finish()
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
                .setNegativeButton("NO") { dialog, _ ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
            dialog.show()
        }
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            finish()
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Product fragment

```
package com.abc.test1


import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.MenuItem
import com.abc.test1.Models.Product
import com.abc.test1.DBHandler.DatabaseHandler
import com.abc.test1.Adapters.ProductRecyclerAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_product.*


/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 *
 */
class ProductFragment : Fragment() {
    var productRecyclerAdapter: ProductRecyclerAdapter? = null
    var fab: FloatingActionButton? = null
    var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    var dbHandler: DatabaseHandler? = null
    var listProducts: List<Product> = ArrayList<Product>()
    var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager? = null
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        initOperations()
        initViews()

    }

    fun initDB() {
        dbHandler = DatabaseHandler(this@ProductFragment.context)
        listProducts = (dbHandler as DatabaseHandler).product()
        context?.let {
            productRecyclerAdapter = this@ProductFragment.context?.let { it1 -> ProductRecyclerAdapter(productsList = listProducts, context = it1)
                }
            (recyclerView as RecyclerView).adapter = productRecyclerAdapter
        }
    }

    fun initViews() {
        val view = view
        fab = view?.findViewById(R.id.fabProduct) as FloatingActionButton
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1) as RecyclerView
        productRecyclerAdapter = this@ProductFragment.context?.let { it1 -> ProductRecyclerAdapter(productsList = listProducts, context = it1) }
        linearLayoutManager = this@ProductFragment.context ?.let{ it1 -> LinearLayoutManager(it1) }
        (recyclerView as RecyclerView).layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
}
    fun initOperations() {
        fabProduct?.setOnClickListener {
            val i = Intent(this@ProductFragment.context, Addproduct::class.java)
            i.putExtra("Mode", "A")
            startActivity(i)
        }
    }
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId
        if (id == R.id.action_delete) {
            val dialog = android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this@ProductFragment.context).setTitle("Info").setMessage("Click 'YES' Delete All Tasks")
                .setPositiveButton("YES") { dialog, _ ->
                    dbHandler!!.deleteAllClient()
                    initDB()
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
                .setNegativeButton("NO") { dialog, _ ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
            dialog.show()
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        initDB()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false)
    }


}
```

Layouts
list_products

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:id="@+id/list_Products"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pName"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/product_name"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000"
                tools:targetApi="jelly_bean"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pPrice"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:text="@string/price"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                tools:targetApi="jelly_bean"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pPc"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:text="@string/ppc"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                tools:targetApi="jelly_bean"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

productmain

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    tools:context=".ClientFragment"
                    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
Product Fragment
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ProductFragment">
    <include layout="@layout/product_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabProduct"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: To help you we need to know on which step data lost. First make sure that you received data from database in correct way if not the problem is on receiving data. If it works fine make sure you are sending correct list to adapter and make sure if while binding adapter receive correct data. If everything correct something wrong on 3rd step on showing result. First of all you need to separate all steps to figure out where the problem is

Comment: Got It! Thank you so much sir. Problem is solved